# AttributeError: 'GELU' object has no attribute 'approximate'

Tags: python, pytorch, yolov5

I get this error when I try to run `train.py` from [this project](https://github.com/DocF/multispectral-object-detection), after first running code on the server:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/multispectral-object-detection-main/test.py", line 326, in <module>
    test(opt.data,
  File "/root/multispectral-object-detection-main/test.py", line 118, in test
    out, train_out = model(img_rgb, img_ir, augment=augment)  # inference and training outputs
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/multispectral-object-detection/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1190, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/root/multispectral-object-detection-main/models/yolo_test.py", line 232, in forward
    return self.forward_once(x, x2, profile)  # single-scale inference, train
  File "/root/multispectral-object-detection-main/models/yolo_test.py", line 265, in forward_once
    x = m(x)  # run
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/multispectral-object-detection/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1190, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/root/multispectral-object-detection-main/models/common.py", line 623, in forward
    x = self.trans_blocks(x)  # dim:(B, 2*H*W, C)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/multispectral-object-detection/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1190, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/multispectral-object-detection/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 204, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/multispectral-object-detection/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1190, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/root/multispectral-object-detection-main/models/common.py", line 545, in forward
    x = x + self.mlp(self.ln_output(x))
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/multispectral-object-detection/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1190, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/multispectral-object-detection/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 204, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/multispectral-object-detection/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1190, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/multispectral-object-detection/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/activation.py", line 684, in forward
    return F.gelu(input, approximate=self.approximate)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/multispectral-object-detection/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1265, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("'{}' object has no attribute '{}'".format(
AttributeError: 'GELU' object has no attribute 'approximate'
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. I edited the post to show proper style for asking questions. There are still some issues with this question. First, if this is someone else's project and you are only trying to run the code, then this is **off topic**: Stack Overflow is about writing the code, not using someone else's. Please instead try the project's issue tracker (it looks like you would have a bug report). If it is your own code, we require the relevant code (please read [mre]) **in the question itself, not** as an off-site link.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try to downgrade to pytorch 1.11 or even 1.10

```bash
conda install pytorch==1.11.0
```

or

```bash
pip install pytorch==1.11.0
```

Comment: Can I delete this parameters 'approximate=self.approximate'? Is there any influence if I do this?

Answer (score 1):

### This trick solves the problem

```
model=torch.load(args.model_load)

# replace all torch-10 GELU's by torch-12 GELU
def torchmodify(name) :
    a=name.split('.')
    for i,s in enumerate(a) :
        if s.isnumeric() :
            a[i]="_modules['"+s+"']"
    return '.'.join(a)
import torch.nn as nn
for name, module in model.named_modules() :
    if isinstance(module,nn.GELU) :
        exec('model.'+torchmodify(name)+'=nn.GELU()')
```

---

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the other answers and adding background.
Newer pytorch versions introduced an optional argument for [GELU](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.GELU.html), `approximate=none||tanh`, the default being `none` (no approximation), which pytorch 1.10 obviosly lacks. You need to alter the old checkpoint and pick a side or downgrade pytorch.

### Solution #1 — keep pytorch version, no GELU approximation, default behavior

```
# load old checkpoint
model=torch.load(args.model_load)
# replace all torch-10 GELU's by torch-12 GELU
def torchmodify(name) :
    a=name.split('.')
    for i,s in enumerate(a) :
        if s.isnumeric() :
            a[i]="_modules['"+s+"']"
    return '.'.join(a)
import torch.nn as nn
for name, module in model.named_modules() :
    if isinstance(module,nn.GELU) :
        exec('model.'+torchmodify(name)+'=nn.GELU()')
```

---

### Solution #2 —  keep pytorch version, approximate GELU

```
# change last line to
exec('model.'+torchmodify(name)+'=nn.GELU(approximate=\'tanh\')')
```

---

### Solution #3 — downgrade pytorch

```
 conda install pytorch==1.10
```

##### Should I approximate it or not?

The general idea from the development team [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/39853) suggests the speed gains from approximating it in recent torch versions are too small to bother. On my graphics card I get slightly better speeds from *not* approximating it. Mileage may vary depending on hardware/torch version.